# How to create a bash function with variable parameters/arguments to grep several keywords/tags

Tags: linux, bash, parameters, tags, grep

I'm using the `:!grep "tag1" filename | grep "tag2" filename | grep -n "tag3 or more" filename` command in vim to search for my code snippets based on their tags (a simple comment at the top of a snippet) in one big file, similar to firefox's tag functionality. I use snippets to remember tricky things.

This is painful to write out each time. I'd like to make an alias, or function to do something like this:

```
:!greptag tag1 tag2 ... tag39
```

And it should search the current doc and return the lines with all the tags on them.

Vim is set to interactive shell mode so that it can parse my bashrc for aliases/functions.

```
set shellcmdflag=-ic "lets vim use bashrc
```

How can I construct a function that allows for variable arguments like this in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use sed:

```
sed e '/tag1/!d;/tag2/!d;.../tagN/!d' filename
```

The `/tag1/!` command is an address prefix to tell sed to only execute the command if the line contains tag1. The command we execute is "d", to delete the line.

A function (in .bashrc) would then be:

```
greptags () {
    local filename="$1"
    shift
    sed "$filename" -e "$(echo "$@" | sed -e 's,\([^ ]*\) *,/\1/\!d;,g')"
}
```

Notice that we use another sed command to parse the arguments into the final sed command list. Basically, for every word (no spaces), we remove the spaces that follows it and put it into the `/tagN/!d;` command form.

And call it:

```
greptags filename tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: The problem is that the original code looks for *all* tags, not *any*.

Comment: Calling this as `$greptags tagname filename` from terminal (int the directory with the sample .txt file) prints out
`sed: -e expression #1, char 20: invalid reference \1 on \`s' command's RHS`

Comment: Sorry... There were a couple of missing things. Fixed it =)

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I love sed.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
greptags() {
 if [[ -z "$1" ]] ; then
  cat
 else
  local t="$1" ; shift
  greptags "$@" | grep "$t"
 fi
}
greptag() {
 local f="$1" ; shift
 local t="$2" ; shift
 grep "$t" "$f" | greptags "$@"
}
```

(untested and, probably not *exactly* what you want, but illustrating the idea).

Comment: It didn't throw any errors, but it's also not working as far as I can tell. I tried with `:!greptags "example_tag" filename` and without the filename and no luck. It doesn't look like I'll be able to avoid learning bash ;p for my reference, which part of your functions allows for multiple args?

Comment: vim don't "see" the bash functions, put the code in a script.

Comment: Actually the other answer worked fine from vim (the bottom 3 lines in my question explains why) after I pasted it into my bashrc, unless I'm missing something and this is formatted specifically to be in a script file.